Why am I more alone and less tolerant of people now?
Since beginning insight practice over ten years ago I have practiced daily and attended many retreats. As a result I feel more peaceful and have gained an understanding and insight into the true nature of reality and I can see clearly the consequences of my actions etc and so I make better choices but it also feels like I have become more alone and less tolerant of people. I do metta practice and do not wish harm to anyone but I'm now painfully aware of the  hatred, ignorance and delusion in the world and I don't like being around people because of it. So I am pretty much a recluse apart from when I see people on retreat and an online Sangha I attend. I feel very compassionate and loving towards animals to the extent that I try hard to not step on ants etc but humans I just don't feel the same way. I guess I see animals as more vulnerable and innocent whereas humans are capable of doing way better but they dont. Instead they just perpetuate greed and violence etc.   Is this a normal part of the path or am I completely misguided?

I may say you are on the right path. But may yet not reach 100%.

I find it helpful to remember that metta doesn't mean love or loving kindness, it means goodwill - being concerned about others' true welfare. As the Buddha often points out, when people are acting well - being generous, keeping the precepts - they're acting in their own best interests. When they're misbehaving they're working for their own harm. What's more, people's behaviours usually have knock-on effects on others who pick up their example. What this means is that when we have genuine goodwill for people at large, we of course want them to act well for their own sake and set a good example for others. And since it is a want - a desire, hence the "will" in goodwill -it can be frustrating and saddening when we see how few people actually do do what's best for themselves and others.
To stop this turning into irritation and anger, the Buddha recommends equanimity - realising that all beings have their own kammic background which sometimes means they've developed long-standing habits that are very hard to break. This helps curb our impatience when we want to see people make immediate changes - most often behavioral changes take a lot of time and effort. Reflecting on the universality of kamma  also entails remembering that, ultimately, it's up to each individual what choices they decide to make in the present - we can advise, encourage and set a good example ourselves but that's all we can do. We can't force people to do what's good for them and usually it backfires when we try. This means that when we see that we can have a positive effect on others we should try our best, but also recognise our limitations and know when to step back. Sometimes this does mean taking time out away from people in general, especially as solitude can be so good for our own wellbeing. This in turn charges our batteries so that we can be of more effective help to others later on.
And yes it can be easier to feel sympathy for animals precisely for the reason that you mention: humans are born into a privileged position that enables them to learn from mistakes and make wise choices, much more so than animals. We thus don't set up such high expectations of animals as we do for humans, and as a result we don't so often get disappointed or upset by them not meeting our expectations. Maybe the answer is learning to lower our expectations for humans, too. We can do this while still wishing the best for them - maintaining an attitude of goodwill and trying to help where we can, while recognising that sometimes our help will not bear immediate fruit, and accepting that some people are just beyond help for the time being.
But it's important to remember this distinction between love and goodwill: you don't need to love someone to wish that they start acting in their own and others' best interests. Similarly love doesn't necessarily make people act in the most beneficial manner, and as the Buddha says it's both a cause of suffering and a cause of hatred. So we need to be careful about confusing the two in case we end up actually developing the causes for suffering rather than developing causes for happiness. It's also important to remember that just because you don't love everyone doesn't mean you hate them or you're a bad person. You say that you care about ants to the point that you avoid stepping on them, but then I bet you don't go stepping on people much either, and likely go even further out of your way to avoid hurting them than you do with ants.
In this case it just sounds like you're annoyed and disappointed with people due to your goodwill and high expectations and need to bring in some realism, patience, understanding and equanimity to counter it.

Related essay: https://www.dhammatalks.org/books/BeyondAllDirections/Section0007.html. Lots of other good resources here: https://www.dhammatalks.org/search/?q=Goodwill+&cat=books&order_by=rank&order=desc

Thank you for taking the time to write this reply. Its very helpful. I'm going to read again and try to let it sink in
